# laravel5 and GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle, guzzle6

I am using GuzzleHttp to send request to external api and get response, but the response returned is empty from data. and when i test a uri and parameters in **advanced rest client**  i get a data,So why Guzzle response is empty?!
please help me if you can.

here is my code:

```
public function index($id)
{
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://qpeople.me/']);

    $response=$client->post('profileinfo', [
        'json'=>[
           'tshirtID'=>$id
        ]
        ]);

    $body=$response->getBody();
    dd($body);
    return view('profile');
}
```

this is the response
[image]

Comment: I don't know laravel's helper functions, but what do you get when you perform dd($response->getBody()->__toString())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,I found the solution by using cURL to send the request and get a response,
here is the code:

```
$url = 'http://qpeople.me/profileinfo';
        $data['tshirtID'] =$id;
        $_data = json_encode($data);
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data),
        );

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<?php
$body = (string) $response->getBody();
dd($body);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22112626)